# How do I connect two divs so that they stay fixed together?

Tags: image, header

I want the header and the main image on a page to stay connected to each other so that when the picture resizes it doesn't become too far off from the header.

But whenever I try to look up the answer, the word "fix" throws off the whole search.

Basically I have two images with divs as containers but I don't know the key words to make them stay/move together.

Comment: Are they next to each other, on top of each other.  Give us a bit more information.

Comment: They are vertically aligned. The header is directly above the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply wrapping them inside an extra div:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Header">Header Text Here </div>
    <div id="Image"><!--- Image Tag here --->  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They overlapped when I put them in the same wrapper div.